# Raspberry Pi DAQHAT: Overvoltage issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, high-voltage, low-pass, arc, daq

I am working on development for a piece of HV test equipment, where I need to monitor the voltage output for a circuit that is actively arcing.

I am measuring the voltage off of a Raspberry Pi DAQHAT (MCC118) which is attached to a capacitive touch screen. Occasionally, when an arcing event is observed, the display will go black. My initial thoughts are that the DAQHAT inputs are receiving voltages that are too high (10 V is the max. the manufacturer recommends).

Upon reading the voltage outputs of the lines going to the DAQHAT, I observed a voltage waveform that looks like a damped oscillator, with a peak voltage of greater than 40 V.

Attached is a diagram of the circuit in question. The lines leading off the image go to the primary side of a neon transformer (115:15000) and some in-line resistance.

[image: Diagram of the circuit in question]

The variac (T002) is attached to a voltage divider, which then runs to a bridge rectifier. On the rectified side, a capacitor is used to smooth the voltage and also act as a low-pass filter. The Zener diode acts as a low impedance path to prevent overvoltages from reaching the DAQHAT.

Is there something that I overlooked that could be the culprit for why I am measuring this damped oscillation overvoltage?

Comment: You are seeing 40V across the 5.1V zener?  Just some quick thoughts: increase the impedances (1k and 15k) to limit current more, use a TVS diode instead of zener for protection.